# Ts3 telnet connection with C#

Tags: c#, telnet, teamspeak

I try to connect to my TeamSpeak 3 server using telnet in a C# application.

By the way, im not very experienced using telnet ^^', so I showed up the telnet Code at the Site
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(VS.80).aspx

The following code should:

1. connect to the teamspeak server
2. send the password and read out the welcome message
3. send the command "help" and read out the help Message

   ```
       string command = "help";

       // creates new TCP client
       TcpClient client = new TcpClient(adress, port);

       // get client stream
       NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

       // send Password
       Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
       stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
       data = new Byte[256];
       Thread.Sleep(200);

       Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
       String responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
       Console.WriteLine(responseData);


       // send the given command
       Byte[] data2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
       stream.Write(data2, 0, data2.Length);
       data2 = new Byte[2560];
       Thread.Sleep(200);

       Int32 bytes2 = stream.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length);
       String responseData2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data2, 0, bytes2);
       Console.WriteLine(responseData2);

       // end stream and client
       stream.Close();
       client.Close();
   ```

The first query works as it should and writes the welcome message into the Console. But at `Int32 bytes2 = stream.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length);` in the seccond query the application stops without giving back any exeption.

Can anyone explain why the I cant read out the Help Message?

Comment: If you're not adverse to using a library I've a NuGet package at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telnet (code at https://github.com/9swampy/Telnet/) that would do all the telnet communications for you...

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I am always happy when I can implement all by myself. So that I know what I'm doing. ^^

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit like that too. Have a look at the code on Github then if you're still stuck. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the application appears to stop is because [`NetworkStream.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) will block if there is no data available to read and the connection is still open. Note that before calling `stream.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length)`, we can see that the [`stream.DataAvailable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable.aspx) property is set to `false`.

[image]

Now, as to why there is no data available: you need to terminate your commands with a line feed so that TeamSpeak knows that the command is complete:

```
string command = "help\n";

...

// send the given command
byte[] data2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
stream.Write(data2, 0, data2.Length);
```

Your first query actually *didn't* succeed, for the same reason. The welcome message is sent by the server on connect; it is not a response to your command. Additionally, I can't see what the value of `password` is, but if you intend to log in the full command is `login <username> <password>`, like so:

> TS3
>   Welcome to the TeamSpeak 3 ServerQuery interface, type "help" for a list of commands and "help <command>" for information on a specific command.
>   **login serveradmin hunter2**
>   error id=0 msg=ok